# Reading a file path that contains wildcard characters

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that takes a directory name as input, and writes a log file to that directory.

This works in most cases:

```
param([string]$output_folder)
$logfile="$output_folder" + "\myscript.log"
Write-Output "logfile: " $logfile
(Get-Date -Format "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]") | Out-file $logfile -Append
```

except when the file path contains a wildcard:

```
E:\Publishing\User manual [en]\
```

This results in an error 'Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path E:\Publishing\User manual [en]\myscript.log did not resolve to a file.

I spent some time trying to sanitize the input, but I haven't found a way that works yet.

```
$logfile='$output_folder' + "\myscript.log"
```

This treats the string as a literal, but that prevents $output_folder from being expanded.

```
param([io.directoryinfo]$output_folder)
```

doesn't help either.

**Edit:**

A comment suggested this:

```
Out-file -LiteralPath $logfile -Append
```

That works for the instances where I use Out-file.

I also call an external program, and I can't use -LiteralPath here:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.8N\bin\Transform.exe" -s:"$inputFile" -xsl:"$output_folder\$transformation_filename" -o:"$outputFile" -t 1>>$logfile 2>&1
```

in fact I have more arguments here that need to be treated as literals. Is there a way so specify this when I create the string?

```
$logfile="$output_folder" + "\myscript.log"
```

Comment: `Out-File -LiteralPath $logfile -Append`

Comment: Thanks, that gets me closer. But I have one command where this doesn't work (I've amended my question).